# Unable to login at http://127.0.0.1:8080/ to ambari

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm Unable to login to `ambari` at `127.0.0.1:8080` after installing `HDP 2.2.4`.  Tried default username/ password as admin/admin and gives me the pop up again and again.

I've enabled `ambari` before trying to run

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default username/password is *maria_dev/maria_dev*. Please follow the walkthrough given at the [official site](https://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/learning-the-ropes-of-the-hortonworks-sandbox/).

You can also ssh into the system using:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

Password would be *hadoop* in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Type `ifconfig` in terminal. You will get a `IP` address starting with `192.168.XX.XXX`. Replace `127.0.0.1` with that `IP` address. It will work.

FYI:

All hadoop services is accessible through the `guest OS IP` address of your sandbox,not through your `local host`.

Comment: I get same IP

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:69:FC:DB
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe69:fcdb/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:48 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:45 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6654 (6.4 KiB)  TX bytes:7058 (6.8 KiB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0xd020

Comment: lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:621 (621.0 b)  TX bytes:621 (621.0 b)

Comment: I think `10.0.2.15`  is your IP. Are you using Virtual BOX?

Comment: Yes I'm using Virtual box. I'm able to access 127.0.0.1:8000 and I've enabled Ambari service.

Comment: Seems there is some compatibility problem with virtual BOX and HDP to access hadoop. I am not sure on it. I will suggests to use VMWare Player to access HDP. But if you are able to access `8000` then `8080` should also work. just disable ambari wait for some time then enable it again and wait for sometime and try accessing it.

Comment: Thank you ! I got where the error is. It's with oracle database. Both using 8080 .